# Limit memory in using isam2

Tags: slam

I'm investigating the usage of the incremental smoothing and mapping class (isam2) in the gtsam package for a real-time image navigation problem. The issue is that while the [API](https://research.cc.gatech.edu/borg/sites/edu.borg/html/a00131.html) has methods for adding factors to the factor graph using isam2::update(...), there is no clear method for removing these factors. Therefore in a real-time (not batch) application, the memory required will grow unbounded.

So the questions are:

1. Is there an API for removing factors and still maintaining a consistent SLAM?
2. How does the isam2 class avoid this memory creep?